# What is the role of all.js and other JS file in font awesome package?

Tags: javascript, fonts, font-awesome

I have downloaded the `font awesome package version 5.7.2` but without using the js files (inside js folder), I haven't confronted any problem and fonts working well. 
[Here](https://fontawesome.com/how-to-use/on-the-web/setup/hosting-font-awesome-yourself) there is a help about js files but only wrote this:

> SVG with JavaScript

But I don't understand what's the meaning.

So what is the role of this js files and are necessary to add in our project?

Comment: It's not necessary to add the js files to your project. The fontawesome website mentions this: `Fewer compatibility concerns because Font Awesome doesn't require JavaScript. `

Answer (score 10):

All.js must be referenced if you want to render svg icons instead of webfont icons, since the svg icons are rendered using javascript. If you go with webfont icons, simply reference All.css and skip the js files.

If you need information to base your decision on, you can read up on the subject here: [Icon Fonts vs SVGs](https://www.keycdn.com/blog/icon-fonts-vs-svgs)

Comment: A fair word of warning - rendering SVG-icons in a table hampers performance incredibly.

Comment: @JohanDanforth, I had that exact issue with rendering SVGs in a table taking 30-40 seconds. Super weird.